# Python Potential OverFlow - Converting Big Floating Number to Integer CHANGES the Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

Consider that I have a float number as below:

```py
>>> x = 820973349107068925.0 
>>> x
8.209733491070689e+17
```

It can be seen that the float number has been automatically converted to scientific notation. **While converting this value to `integer`, the whole value changes.**
I have tried the following:

```py
>>> int(x)
820973349107068928
>>> np.int64(x)  
820973349107068928
>>> np.uint64(x)
820973349107068928
>>> '%i' % x     
'820973349107068928'
>>> '%d' % x
'820973349107068928'
```

It might be due to a potential overflow that I'm not aware of. Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Dont work with big numbers by float operation. Float numbers has calculation inaccuracy. Best practic for big numbers - only int objects and only int operations (```+```, ```-```, ```%```, ```//```). Not use ```/```!!!

Comment: Read recipes in documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html